# How to call ajax request for admin in HMVC structure in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have created HMVC structure from [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) and using both front and admin panel in same module. The problem is when calling ajax in admin_user in user module, it's returning 404 not found error.

**Structure**

```
myproject
|_ application  
  |_ modules  
    |_ user  
      |_ controllers  
         |_ User.php  
         |_ Admin_user.php 
      |_ models
        |_ User_model.php
        |_ Admin_user_model.php
      |_ views
         |_ admin
           |_ (All Admin Views)
         |_ (All Front Views)
```

**Routing**

```
$route['admin/user']='user/admin_user';
```

I have tried bellow ajax urls so far, but no luck it shows same 404 not found error.

1. http://localhost/projects/myproject/web/admin/user/ajaxChanageStatus
2. http://localhost/projects/myproject/web/admin_user/ajaxChanageStatus
3. http://localhost/projects/myproject/web/user/admin_user/ajaxChanageStatus
4. http://localhost/projects/myproject/web/user/admin/user/ajaxChanageStatus

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       $(document).on('click','.user-status',function(){
           var nUserId = $(this).attr('data-id');
           $.post(base_url+'admin/user/ajaxChanageStatus',{nUserId:nUserId},function(res){
               $(this).find('i').class(res);
           });
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: remove your route and try to access it without your route - which version are u using? (both CI and HMVC),

Comment: @sintakonte Its worked !!!... but how do I use routing ?
btw I am using 3.1.3 ci version and 5.5 HMVC version